# Nested function causing troubles

Tags: python, function, module, package

I've got a Python script.
I've had several functions in this script which I decided to move to a 'package' folder beside the main script.
In this folder, I created a *.py file where I put all my functions.
I've placed an empty **init**.py near this file within the 'package' folder.

When starting the code of my main script with:

```
from package_folder.my_functions import *
```

the script works well when calling every functions from that file.

But when trying to import it directly:

```
import package_folder.my_functions
```

it doesn't seems to work as well as with the above technique.

The cause seems to be the fact that in the file well*my_functions.py*, I have a function that needs an other one, declared previously in that file.
I had this obscure error on that function that needs an other one:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Is this permissible and if not, how to manage this case?

Comment: can you try `import package_folder.my_functions.func1`, where `func1` is the function name inside `my_functions.py` file

Comment: I have read out that using wild-card is not a really good idea, that's why I asked.

Comment: yeah, wild-card imports is not really a good idea, then you should do it like `from package_folder.my_functions import func1, func2`, where `func1` and `func2` are the functions name inside `my_functions.py` file

Comment: It may be fast a pain to load plenty of functions like that isn't it?

Comment: it's pain, but good in terms of avoiding namespace pollution that may occur because of wildcard imports.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally not a good idea to use from module import *. Wildcard importing leads to namespace pollution; you imported more names than you need and if you accidentally refer to an imported name you may not get the NameError you wanted.

Also, if a future version of the library added additional names, you could end up masking other names, leading to strange bugs still:

**Example**

```
from my_mod1 import func1
from my_mod2 import *
```

If you upgrade `my_mod2` and it now includes a `my_mod2.func1` it'll replace the `my_mod1.func1` import in the 1st line.